# Laravel paginate on query builder

Tags: php, laravel

If i use

```
$categories= Category::orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
```

it works but if i use

```
$categories= Category::with('subcategories')->orderby('id', 'desc')->paginate(3);
```

paginate doesn't work! how to fix it?

UPDATE:

```
<tbody>
@foreach ($categories as $category)
 @foreach($category->subcategories as $sub)
  <tr>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $sub->id }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $sub->title }}</td>
    <td class="text-center">{{ $sub->category->title }}</td>
  </tr>
 @endforeach
@endforeach
</tbody>
```

Comment: What doesn't work? What's the error?

Comment: all data will load in first page instead of being divided to pages. seems like not using pagination.

Comment: how do you print the pages? its terrific! we are in panic! we even don't have time to write an [mcve question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @BagusTesa Updated...

Comment: So you're getting more than three `$category`s per page? As subcategories are not paginated.

Comment: yes. And also they are not actually ordered by id! i guess they ordered by id of category and not subcategories.

Comment: You don't even have `order` in the second example...

Comment: that was before let me edit it!

Comment: Update the question with the error or the error message

Comment: What are you actually expecting the output to be? Your query will get a paginated list of **categories** NOT **subcategories**, ordered by ID. I get the sense that you actually want a paginated list of **subcategories** ordered by ID.

Comment: @ljubadr there is no error! it shows but instead of getting only 3 will get 10 and not ordered.

Comment: That's because your query doesn't do what you think it does.

Comment: @fubar i know it doesn't and that's why i'm here bro :) help me to get what i want.

Comment: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for all helps and negative rates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to approach this problem from the opposite side of the relationship.

Find all subcategories, with their parent category, order them by ID descending and then paginate to three per page.

```
$subcategories = Subcategory::with('category')
    ->orderBy('id', 'desc')
    ->paginate(3);

<tbody>
    @foreach($subcategories as $subcategory)
        <tr>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $subcategory->id }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $subcategory->title }}</td>
            <td class="text-center">{{ $subcategory->category->title }}</td>
        </tr>
    @endforeach
</tbody>
```